# D3 dynamically assign stroke-width on a line

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to achieve similar line effect to the one visible on those charts: https://www.informationisbeautifulawards.com/showcase/2873-a-night-under-the-stars
To build my visualization I use React + d3. 
This is the code for my line:

```
var avgWeekday = d3.selectAll('.radial').append("path")
      .datum(this.props.avgWeekday)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "#2A41E5")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.value; })
      .attr("d", line);
```

The line is rendered properly but the stroke width is not assigned, what am I doing wrong here?

The data from this.props.avgWeekday looks like this: 
[image]

However when I actually try to print it inside stroke-width function I get undefined.

Comment: Hi - we would need to see the data in this.props.avgWeekday and what you expect d.value to be?

Comment: Please refer to edited question :)

Comment: Hi - Unfortunately a svg line can't have variable stroke-width along its length. To recreate that example, you would need to use a Path, possibly using something like this technique https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048740